# Burn Track Info/Tags to Audio CD

Tags: audio, mp3, music, compact-disc, music-management

I am using MusicBee in Window7 to burn custom recordings (MP3 files) to an audio cd. The MP3 files have all the track information ('tags' in musicbee) filled out. When I burn the files to a cd using the MusicBee "Burn Disc" tool and the "audio cd" option, none of the track information is burned to the cd.

Does anyone know how to burn the track info to the audio cd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred choice of software ImageBurn does some of what you asking for as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: wow, i had no idea writing CD-Text was such a special thing. Seems like such a simple thing.  Thanks for the answer. I understand the technology behind this better now.